# Flutter check if an action was done on another app

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to create an app where it validates an action was done on another app, is this possible in Flutter? I've looked around and I can't seem to find anything.

An example: I click on a button and it opens Instagram, it listens to see if I have pressed the Instagram FOLLOW button and proceeds only after it's done, if I have not pressed the button then the program doesn't continue.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you cant do this (Well, definitely not on iOS, not sure about Android but I would imagine not)

Comment: How do people build these apps where you have to complete a task to earn points etc? How do they verify whether the user has actually done the tasks?

Comment: I don't know but you should refer to [3.2.2 (vi)](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#other-business-model-issues).